# EOFError: EOF when reading a line. Python

Tags: python

```
while True:
    a=int(input()) 
    while True:
        if a<10 or a>100:
            break
        else:
            print(a)
            break
```

Output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 2, in 
    a=int(input()) 
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

**Помогите пожалуйста**

Comment: Это точно весь код? При выполнении данного кода не происходит такой ошибки.

Comment: `break` прерывает внутренний `while` - а кто прервёт внешний? да и нафига нужен внутренний?

Comment: "
Это точно весь код? При выполнении данного кода не происходит такой ошибки. "

Да, это весь код

Comment: "break прерывает внутренний while - а кто прервёт внешний? да и нафига нужен внутренний? "

Его не нужно прерывать, нужно, чтобы пользователь вводил числа, если они меньше 100 и больше 10 оно выводилось, а цикл должен быть бесконечным

Comment: Как запускаете? У себя на компьютере или в каком-то онлайн курсе?

Comment: онлайн задача, у них на сайте свой IDE

Comment: @cxnnxrdvsh, тогда добавьте в вопрос текст задания и желательно ссылку на само задание.

Comment: решил другим методом, спасибо!